# Where to find statistical prevalence data for psychopathology over time?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, statistics

Are there any places where is possible to find historical data for trends of psychological disease?

For example some Google website (similar to google trends or [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams))

Comment: Prevalence would be difficult to disentangle from changes in diagnostic methods and criteria over time, not to mention public awareness. Mental health is a young science. If you're concerned with prevalence over time on the scale of years but not decades, that might be manageable. I bet records could be found for the last decade or so.

Comment: A really interesting answer.. There is a friend of mine which is making some searches about stereotypes and mass media consequences. He said that a lot of researches shows correlation between television and negative consequences on the population. I guess there are also strong influences towards anorexia for example. But it'a a mix between social psychology and clinical psychology...

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for, but the [Wisonsin longitudinal study database](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/wlsresearch/), or similar, might be useful?

Comment: The global burden of disease data set has data from 1990, 2000, and 2010 on a country by country and disease by disease level.  
http://ghdx.healthmetricsandevaluation.org/record/global-burden-disease-study-2010-gbd-2010-results-cause-1990-2010-country-level

Comment: @honi: I've not understood your comment totally, can it become an answer?

Comment: Is [this](https://doi.org/10.1111/jcpp.12372) the sort of thing you are looking for?